# the find() wont work in a function just firefox giving this fatal error

Tags: php, firefox

I am getting this fatal error from the following code :

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in on
>   line 12

The coogle chrome not giving this fatal error i get this error on firefox

```
$get_content = file_get_html($get_url);
foreach ($get_content->find('title') as $element) {
   @$page_title = $element->plaintext;
}
if(empty($page_title)) {
   $page_title = '';
}
```

What is the solution anyone can help me please?

Comment: `file_get_html()` likely returns false or null on failure, you'll need to account for that possibility.

Comment: @AlexHowansky you'll help me figure out how to do it. Google chrome does not show such an error. I just see this error on firefox.

Comment: Just run `var_dump($get_content);` to see what's in it, it's probably boolean false.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yet is is bool(false)

Comment: So then your call to `file_get_html()` failed. There should be a detailed entry in your error log.

Comment: @AlexHowansky But i get this error just in firefox not google chrome.

Comment: @AlexHowansky You are trying to help but i am telling it, this fatal error will be come just on firefox not other browser giving this error. the find() is working fine all other browsers.